# Where can I find altcoin inflation rates?

Tags: exchanges, altcoin, trading, value, inflation

I know I can use [coincap.io](http://coincap.io/) and [CoinMarketCap](http://coinmarketcap.com/) to see a lot of good information about altcoin relative values, and [cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/) has good detailed information, but where can I access inflation rates for each currency?

I could find the info by reading white papers one by one, but I'm sure someone out there has already done this?

Comment: Inflation, on **any** cryptocoin?

Comment: Right, for example there will only ever be 21 million bitcoin, so inflation should trend to 0, where something like Tether has no set limit. How can I know what the future supply of the currency will be without reading hundreds of whitepapers?

Comment: Correct only 21m. You cannot buy something that does not exist, no trend, no inflation. If there is no limit, there is no inflation. Its as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sites will help this is from which ones I get all info normally
https://etherscan.io 
or
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer
or 
https://www.coinlore.com/